# Append the rowNumber() with max value in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Hi I am working on a requirement where I am using rownumber() function to get the linenumbers it is working fine when I insert the first batch of the rows in a file but the issue is when I insert the new batch with same Id, the line number is starting from 1. I want to continue from the max value of the Id as below

For First Batch of rows insertion

```
OrderID   Row#   ConfirmationID
---------  ----  -------------
258584048   1   285477904
258584048   2   285477905
258584048   3   285477907
258584048   4   285477908
```

For Secon Batch of rows insertion again it is starting from 1

```
OrderID   Row#   ConfirmationID
---------  ----  -------------
258584048   1   285477911
258584048   2   285477912
258584048   3   285477913
258584048   4   285477914
```

I am expecting the result as below

```
OrderID   Row#   ConfirmationID
---------  ----  -------------

258584048   1   285477904
258584048   2   285477905
258584048   3   285477907
258584048   4   285477908 
258584048   5   285477911
258584048   6   285477912
258584048   7   285477913
258584048   8   285477914

row_number() over(PARTITION BY OrderID order by OrderID)
```

Comment: Why dont use an identity or sequenced colum?

Comment: The requirement is each partition will have set of line numbers for each ID. Id is repeated, if I use sequence I can not have line numbers for each row in respect to orderId

Comment: This sounds very brittle to me but you could use a subquery to help.

Comment: These are set of ID's with linenumbers each ID should have unique line number starting from 1.

Answer (score 0):

This a bit of strange requirement but you could do something like this.

```
row_number() over(PARTITION BY OrderID order by OrderID) + (select max(OrderID) from YourTable where OrderID = [YourInsertingOrderID])
```

Comment: Sean, Thanks for the response i will try out this

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Sean answer in case you have more than one order id being input at the same time:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable(OrderID,   Row,   ConfirmationID)
SELECT yst.OrderId
, row_number() over(PARTITION BY yst.OrderID order by yst.ConfirmationID) + ISNULL(xt.maxByOrder, 0)
, yst.ConfirmationId
FROM yourSourceTable yst
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  select max(yt.Row) as maxByOrder, yt.OrderID 
  from yourtable yt
  group by yt.OrderId
) xt ON xt.OrderId = yst.OrderId
WHERE... -- Filter in your source table to get the records you want to insert
```

Also, I have modified the `ORDER BY` for the `ROW_NUMBER` function, as sorting by `OrderId` does nothing when you are already partitioning by `OrderId`. I have set the `ConfirmationID` as ordering field, but feel free to change it back if it doesn't fit your requirements.

Even further, if you have a filter, you could improve the subquery to only return the max values for those orders that are included in the records that you are about to insert in the table.

Comment: Thanks Jorge for the response, I will try and let you know

Comment: Jorge its really awesome, I am able to get the expected result, Thanks a lot once again...